# React Client-side fetched URL doesn't match server-side requested URL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js, google-authentication

I'm working on a small nodejs-express-react app. I'm sending a request against the Google Analytics Management API server-side then trying to fetch the response from the client-side. It doesn't work as the Status Code of the fetch is `Status Code: 405`. however, I'm seeing that the fetched URL is not the same as the requested URL. I don't understand what is wrong exactly.

I'm fetching `/auth/google/callback` but according to the network information and looking at the error the url requested is `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&client_id=XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com`

Here is the full error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&client_id=XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback') from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have this on the server-side:

```
app.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ['Profile','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'] })
);

app.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/error", session: false }),
    function(req, res) {
        var token = req.user.token;
    request('https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts?access_token=' + token,  
function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(body).items);
res.send({data:JSON.parse(body).items})
});
    }
);
```

And this on the client-side:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/auth/google/callback',    {
          method: 'GET',
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
          credentials: 'same-origin'
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(user => this.setState({ data: data }));
  }
```

How should I structure my node/express back-end so I can make the react-side fetch work correctly?

EDIT: I've added `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` in the header but still got the error.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch('/auth/google/callback'` requires a full URL (for example https://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback)

**EDIT**

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
}
```

Comment: does your server method work if you test it with Postman for example?

Comment: yes. If I'm reaching /auth/google directly I have can see the response from the API

Comment: looks like the client is the issue then, let's focus on that

Comment: also "fetched URL is not the same as the requested URL" what do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200528/discussion-between-simon-breton-and-horatiu-jeflea).